# Create random list of given length from a list of strings in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, random

I have a list of strings:

```
lst = ["orange", "yellow", "green"]
```

and I want to randomly repeat the values of strings for a given length.

This is my code:

```
import itertools
lst = ["orange", "yellow", "green"]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 2) for x in lst))
```

This implementation repeats but not randomly and also it repeats equally, whereas it should be random as well with the given length.

Comment: What result do you eexpect ? The length is the global final ? Please clarify with examples in your post

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you need, Do you want a list that has a random value given in the input list with the same length

Comment: i want list of length (1,150) where strings("orange", "yellow" and "green") are repeated randomly i.e, ["orange","yellow","orange","yellow","green",...........,"green"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```python
import random
lst = ["orange", "yellow", "green"]
[lst[random.randrange(len(lst))] for i in range(100)]
```

Explanation:

- `random.randrange(n)` returns an integer in the range `0` to `n-1` included.
- the list comprehension repeatedly adds a random element from `lst` 100 times.
- change `100` to whatever number of elements you wish to obtain.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the
> population sequence or set.

Simply set `k` to be 1 each time you call it. This gives you a *list* of length 1, randomly selected from the source list.

To generate a large random list, repeatedly call `random.sample()` in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), e.g. 150 times. (Of course, you have to also index the resulting list from `random.sample()` so that you retrieve just the value rather than a list of length 1).

For example:

```
import random
lst = ["orange", "yellow", "green"]
print([random.sample(lst, k=1)[0] for i in range(150)])
# Output
# ['green', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'green', ...
```